Unable to retrieve the transaction log of a wallet using Ethers.js
I am trying to retrieve a list of all the transactions a wallet has executed on the Ethereum Mainnet but I keep getting an empty array as the result. Could you please help me fix it? Please see the code below.
import { ethers } from "ethers";

const endpointURL = "https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/8e9f219935524dd7ac8a469c9367c4b7";
const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider(endpointURL);

const currentBlockNumber = await provider.getBlockNumber();

// Block number on January 01, 2024 at 00:00:00 UTC. 
const startBlockNumber = 18908894;

const walletAddress = "0x6843a2F81aCc7f5903359230E54E667703416DD4";

const walletTransactionLog = await provider.getLogs(
  {
    address: walletAddress,   
    fromBlock: startBlockNumber,
    toBlock: currentBlockNumber
  }
);

console.log(walletTransactionLog);

I tried changing the endpoint providers but that didn't work. It keeps returning an empty array.
[]

